# rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gemfile

I am trying to update my ROR app which is currently Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.2.4

I am trying to move to Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.4, which is the minimum to get MongoDB 3.2 to run.

When I changed my Gemfile to Ruby 2.2.2 and run `bundle install`, and `bundle update` I get rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.10

Why is it resolving it to 4.2.10 when I have rails set to (~> 4.2.4) in my Gemfile?

Gemfile below.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.4'
gem 'mongo', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.12.1'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0'
# mongoid seemed to want these to run the generator
gem 'execjs', '~> 2.6.0'
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.2'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.2'
gem 'grape', '~> 0.13.0'
#gem 'grape-swagger'
gem 'thin', '~> 1.6.4'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.2.11'
#gem 'mongoid_geospatial'
gem 'kaminari', '~>1.0.0' # pagination
#gem 'iron_worker_ng', '~> 1.6.6'
gem 'iron_worker', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.13.2.302'
gem 'newrelic-grape', '~> 2.0.0'
#gem "opentok"
gem 'mandrill-api', '~> 1.0.53'
gem 'aws-sdk', "~> 1"
gem 'nexmo', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.15.4', :ref => '69db6635c2630ffd63c1858646cbc280226f31a7bc34e1c9d1322c2c73e1e386'
#gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby', :ref =>'df2e36287d88726c6a03ec6c1fdc19b5d6e2b274'
gem 'stripe', '~> 1.22.0'
gem 'gibberish', "~> 2.0.0"
#gem 'mongoid-encrypted-fields', :path => "./vendor/plugins/mongoid-encrypted-fields-1.2.2"
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'gcm', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'chronic', '~> 0.10.2'
gem 'oauth2', '~> 1.1.0'# for stripe connect
gem 'aescrypt', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'houston', '~> 2.2.3'
gem 'hashids', '~> 1.0.3'
gem 'rack-cors', '~> 0.4.0', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'mail', '~> 2.6.4'
gem 'sendgrid-ruby', '~> 1.1.6'

group :production, :staging do
    gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.6.0'
  gem 'timecop', '~> 0.8.0'
  gem 'debugger', '~> 1.6.8'
  gem 'typhoeus', '~> 0.8.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
#group :assets do
#  gem 'sass-rails'
#  gem 'coffee-rails'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

#  gem 'uglifier'
#end
gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.7.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.5'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The squiggly arrow `~>` symbol means the last minor version will be updated to the latest version. So `4.2.4` will be resolved to `4.2.X` where X is the latest available.

If you want to stick to `4.2.4`, use `=` like `gem 'rails', '= 4.2.4'`.

Comment: If it cannot find compatible version does it just go with what was last used?

Comment: "compatible" with what?

Comment: I am running bundle install all of the above errors are saying it cannot find compatible versions.

Comment: I just answered "Why is it resolving it to 4.2.10 " which was your question

Comment: @jdog On a side note, you *probably* aught to be using `4.2.10`, not `4.2.4`. Unless you have a good reason not to (which you have not articulated in your question), it's highly unlikely that there is a compatibility issue between those patch releases. It's far *more* likely that you'll benefit from the various bug fixes and improvements that were added to the patch release.

Comment: @jdog But as said above, you need to **show us the error** in order for us to give any specific advice about resolving said error. We're not mind readers.